# Create a standalone library module in Android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Creating a standalone library application is a common task in Eclipse + ADT.
I thought that this should be a simple task in Android Studio (1.2 or above), but after struggling with this problem for two days, I figured out that google did nothing about this and implementing a standalone library module is not as simple as I thought. So I decided to share my experiences with you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To create a standalone and reusable library module in Android Studio:

1- Create a new project with no Activity.

2- New project's default module is named `app`. Right click on module and  refactor/rename it to something like 'library'. Close Android Studio.

3- Open file explorer and rename module's folder from `app` to `library`.

4- Open `.idea` folder. There are some XML files there that have references to `app` folder. Replace `app` into `library` in these files.

5- Open module's gradle file (library/build.gradle) and change plugin to `com.android.library`. Then remove `applicationId`.

6- Open Android Studio. Rebuild module. If there is no error, we are done here.

7- Open application which is dependent on that module. Open `settings.gradle` and include `library` module as below:

```
include ':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File('/Path/To/LibraryProject/library')
```

8- Open application's `app` module `build.gradle` file and add this line into `dependencies` section:

```
compile project(':library')
```

9- Rebuild your project. If everything is right, you will see `library` module in your project. You can edit `library` module from there and/or its project and more important: Now you have a standalone library module that you can reuse in multiple projects!

I hope google will make this process a lot easier in future releases of Android Studio!

EDIT:

I checked Android Studio version 1.4 and hopefully in this version we can omit steps 3 and 4.

Comment: This answer is a godsend. Nowhere else could I find that I had to edit those files in the .idea folder.